# Existence of subset of blocks who total weight lies in an interval

Tags: combinatorics

I am doing the following problem:

---

You are given a set of $n$ blocks, each weighing at least $1$; their total weight is $2n$. Prove that for every real number $r$ with $0 \leq r \leq 2n-2$ you can choose a subset of the blocks whose total weight is at least $r$ but at most $r + 2$.

---

I have thought of using induction, but I am stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there is always a subset of the set of blocks with total weight at least $r$. So let $M$ be a minimal subset with weight at least $r$. Consider $b\in M$ a block with the smallest weight among the blocks in $M$. Then the weight of $M\setminus\{b\}$ is less than $r$, so the weight of $b$ is at least 3. Can you conclude the result from this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

It is easy to argue that for a given $r, \, 0 \le r \le (2n-2)$, if the total weight of the subset for all subsets of length $\lfloor r \rfloor$ or less from the $2n$ blocks is

(i) $\lt r \,$ then the maximum total weight of $n$ blocks will be $n$ which is not possible.
(ii) $\ge (r + 3) \,$ then the minimum total weight of $n$ blocks will be $3n$ which is not possible.